# Migration from VS 2008 to VS2012 or VS 2013

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2008, migration, visual-studio-2013

I recently migrated my VC++ 6.0 application code to Visual studio 2008 in Windows 7. Now, I would like to migrate my project again to Visual studio 2012/2013 in Windows 7. Which is prefered and why?

1. Visual studio 2008 to visual studio 2012
   or
2. Visual studio 2008 to visual studio 2013

Please advise.

Thanks!
Ankush

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just migrate directly to VS2013.  The changes between VS2012 and VS2013 are minor and none of them game-breaking.

I would also suggest looking at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/06/27/what-s-new-for-visual-c-developers-in-vs2013-preview.aspx and maybe the official MSDN articles

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386063(v=vs.110).aspx for VS2012
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386063(v=vs.120).aspx for VS2013

This may alert you to anything you might want to change\investigate before upgrade.  At the end though if your goal is VS2013 then just do 1 upgrade, 1 set of tests etc.